# Can not view the Google map in  Mapview Activity

Tags: android-manifest

I had created and added the Map key to my xml file,and also added the users library and internet permission to the manifest file ,the application runs fine but i can not view the Google map, instead of that i'm getting only the grids,any body come across this issue , please help me..Mithun

Answer (score 0):

I have had same issue in past. It was related to key provided. But mine problem was using a different computer to compile my application- so debug keystore was different.

I mean when registering key for map i had to use my debug keystore and when changing my computer the debug keystore changed too, therefor google maps key not valid anymore.

Have you fallowed these steps? http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

Comment: thank you for the helpful suggestion , i'm very sorry to say that my problem was because of my careless,i had added the users permission inside the application node of my manifest file that was my problem, now my application is working fine